# Please add a syntax highlighting hint to these tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, syntax-highlighting

The following version specific tags should have syntax-highlighting enabled, like the also listed non-specific tag:

[kr-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kr-c)
[c89](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c89) ([c90](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c90) should be synonymized to it anyway)
[c11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c11)
Base tag is [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c), which already has proper highlighting.

[c++98](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b98) [c++03](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b03) [c++-1y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-1y)
Base tag is [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), which already has proper highlighting.
These version specific tags already have proper highlighting: [c++-0x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-0x) [c++-11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-11)

Comment: Wouldn't it suffice to add the base tag to the question?

Comment: In the vast majority of cases, adding the base tag is right for the question. Still, to date all feature-requests for enforcing such were declined and I don't see that changing. Anyway, the version-specific tags should consistently be enough to enable syntax-highlighting.

Comment: Why? They're low-use tags (the most popular one has a little over 200 questions) and the vast majority of these questions *already* have a [tag:c] or [tag:c++] tag on them. Just add the appropriate tag to the ones that don't. We're not going to go through *every single* one-off tag on Stack Overflow and add a highlighting option to it.

Comment: @animuson is the reason for not going through single one-off tags a matter of time / effort or are there system  / performance  implications that you should take into account?