# Default highlighting for pandas, scipy and numpy should be set to Python

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

Umm, that's about it - as the title says [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas), [scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scipy) and [numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpy) should all have a default language of [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) until an editor comes along and addresses a missing [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag or otherwise (in very rare cases) introduces an explicit language to a code block.

Comment: Why should they need it? As you say, the error is omitting the [tag:python]-tag, not the missing highlighting making it obvious.

Comment: @Deduplicator I'm not disputing they're missing the proper tag... but since they're all libraries that use Python -- there's not a reason for those to **not** have that highlighting, surely?

Comment: jQuery seems to have a "default" which ends up as JS... what's the difference?

Comment: Number of posts? At least animuson seems to think that's important: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262764/please-add-a-syntax-highlighting-hint-to-these-tags#comment54142_262764 Still, taking a second look, at least some of them might have enough questions to warrant that. (The tags in that question seem to have lost quite a lot since...)

Comment: @Deduplicator I'm not ripping my hair out when I come across them (they are on my favourite tags), going "omg - why didn't they tag it with the language, and why am I going through effectively plain text - when it should be Python" kind of thing... if it's a mixed Q between "using a data.frame in R, how would I do it using a pandas DataFrame" I could accept some ambiguity... in the vast majority of the 100's of Q's I read... I see no reason to **not** default

Answer (score 5):

I don't think that's necessary, and I believe it was a mistake to allow such a thing for other libraries/frameworks.

Instead of adding highlighting to library/framework tags I believe it would be better if, when posting a question without any language tag specified, the poster was warned about the missing tag.

He could always ignore the warning if the question he's asking doesn't contain any code, but since almost all good SO questions require code written in some language, most of the time a missing language tag is a signal of a bad or off topic question.

This has two advantages:

- Less missing tags in questions
- Less work for the SO team. New frameworks are developed every year, so this requires constant changing of tag properties. New languages aren't developed at that speed.

Comment: So simply as it is, if the post contains any code and there is no tag that specifies a language, it will warn about it. Seems clever, I thought it would be already this way, never forgot my code language tags at all.

Comment: *"... but since almost all good SO questions require code..."* [it's actually quite a bit less than "almost all"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338846/4639281)