# Downvoting vs. flagging poor questions

Tags: discussion, questions, flags, downvotes, low-quality-posts

I've just come across a question which seems marginally low-quality. The OP was stuck on a basic logic problem; the question wasn't written clearly so is unlikely to be useful for anyone else. (If the OP had written a clear question the answer would probably have also been clear.)

Is it useful to *always* flag such questions? Or is it sufficient just to downvote them? Does gratuitous flagging pollute the flag review queues?

Also is it harmful to answer such questions? (Which I did.)

Comment: It is useful to edit such question into shape. If that doesn't work and needs to be looked after by the OP a close vote/flag is in order. On top of that use voting to indicate to future visitors: *this is not a good question, be careful.*

Comment: Relevant: [**If you need to bend a close reason to fit the question in order to justify closure, the closure isn't really justified.**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338846/4639281). Basically, if the question is answerable and on-topic, answer it. If it is off-topic, close it. If you can improve it, edit it. If it is not answerable, but not off-topic, and not editable, just downvote and move on.

Comment: Thanks. The question was answerable and trivial and not likely to be useful again, so I think answering and downvoting was the right thing to do in this particular case.

Comment: @TinyGiant: To be a bit pedantic, there are other valid close reasons other than "off-topic", which can apply to not answerable questions, when the question is not, necessarily,  off-topic: A) Duplicate, B) unclear what you're asking, C) too broad, and D) primarily opinion based. Arguably, B, C, and D could also be considered "off-topic". While I believe you intended to include all these when you said "off-topic", I've seen too many statements, even from comments, taken very literally and applied generally. (also removal reasons: E) spam, F) rude or abusive).

Comment: All I can think of is this: https://cdn.meme.am/cache/instances/folder366/62440366.jpg

Comment: @Mayken did you read the post linked in my comment? I chose off-topic to mean clsoure, and left flaggable offenses as impled, because "if it is not off-topic, too broad, primarily opinion based, unclear, spam, rude, abusvie, gibberish, nonsense, or otherwise in violation of site policy..." seemed a bit wordy.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> Is it useful to always flag such questions?

That depends. If the question should be closed, use one of the flags for "this question should be closed." But please do not use a custom flag or inappropriate flag. For example, please don't flag as spam something that isn't actually spam.

> Or is it sufficient just to downvote them?

If the question shouldn't be closed but just isn't a good question (lacks research, for example), just a downvote is fine.

> Does gratuitous flagging pollute the flag review queues?

Yes, if it's really gratuitous! If you mean, "Does *lots* of flagging pollute the queues?", then no. Flag whenever appropriate, but be sure you use the right type of flag. Don't use a custom flag, for example, if a standard flag will do.

> Also is it harmful to answer such questions? (Which I did.)

If it is a bad question, but not one that should be closed, it's fine to answer. I have answered a lot of questions that I also downvoted. But if it should be closed, then answering is wasting your time, at best, and encouraging more bad questions to boot. In other words, flag or answer, but don't do both.

Comment: Also, if it is a bad question but, you could understand suffice to answer, maybe you should *consider* an edit. Obviously improving, not changing the question.

Comment: I have seen questions with downvotes where all the answers were downvoted too. Is this the "right" thing to do?

Comment: @distante that would depend on the answers.

Comment: @distante you're free to vote however you like. Typically, if I down-vote a garbage question, I'll down-vote the answers as well... in the hope that it serves as a deterrent to answering such crap in the future. That said, sometimes an answer really is extraordinary, despite the terrible question -in which case I'd up-vote the answer and maybe even try to salvage the question through edits. You have full autonomy with your votes.

Comment: @distante  You trap a user with a potentially unsalvageable question by answering something that should be closed, so that's something to keep in mind as well.

Answer (score 9):

> Is it useful to always flag such questions? Or is it sufficient just to downvote them?

This should be answered in a case-by-case basis. Do any of the flagging or closing reasons apply to the question? If so, flag and vote to close as appropriate. If the issues are relatively minor and you can see a way to solve them by editing without rewriting the question entirely or having to guess what the OP is thinking, edit the question into something better. If no flagging or closing reason fits, and in spite of that the question is flawed in a way that isn't trivial to fix, just downvote it.

> Also is it harmful to answer such questions? (Which I did.)

If you have flagged or voted to close, you shouldn't answer it -- it would be an incoherent course of action. If you have merely downvoted it, it is not necessarily wrong to answer. Personally, if I downvote a question it is unlikely that I will feel like bothering with writing an answer to it, but that's just me.

Answer (score 6):

> the question wasn't written clearly so is unlikely to be useful for anyone else

If you can't edit it to make it clear, there's a close vote for that: unclear what you are asking. Questions needs to transmit enough context to be answerable. If that context is obfuscated, it's more difficult to answer them. Try to edit if you think you can deobfuscate the question; otherwise, flag the question as in need of closure. If I can't understand the question well enough to be able to edit it, I wouldn't answer it, either.

Answer (score 4):

> is it sufficient just to downvote them?

In short no.  I recommend *always* adding a comment in conjunction with a downvote.

I believe the rep system guides us some on downvoting - as users with less rep have little choice but to downvote, while higher rep enables us to use more ways to make SE better 1 question at a time: editing, flagging, commenting.

When I downvote anything - I always include a comment to explain and hopefully guide the author toward improving - to recover from a downvotable act.

It is my hope that I can encourage a person who earns a downvote to make some improvement or edit that will turn a negative experience into a constructive and positive experience.

Comment: I fully agree. Just downvoting helps no-one. Without a comment nobody can tell if a downvote is justified (the downvoter *might* be an idiot who thinks he knows more than he does, for instance).

Comment: @Dsm (1/2) "Just downvoting helps no-one" -- The primary goal of downvoting is not helping the asker, but supporting the curation of posts by the community. From that perspective, a downvote without a comment can be perfectly helpful.

Comment: @Dsm (2/2) "the downvoter might be an idiot who thinks he knows more than he does, for instance" -- Or someone else might have left a comment pointing out the same issue that led to the downvote. Or the OP should have known better after posting the fifth consecutive poorly received question with the same issues that the previous ones had. Or the question is so egregiously bad that it is obvious the OP completely ignored the advice given to new users. One of the reasons the system does not require explicit justification for downvotes is that there are plenty of cases in which it is superfluous.

Comment: @duplode I am not sure I agree that a comment w/a downvote is "superfluous" - except if perhaps the community needs the downvotes and downvoters can't spare the time to put a simple phrase in the comments to add info to the downvote.

Comment: @condiosluzverde I said "[in] plenty of cases", and not always. For instance, it is clearly pointless to have five identical comments accompanying five downvotes cast for the same reason. Furthermore, [there are other reasons why downvote comments aren't mandatory](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285777/2751851).

Comment: @duplode - very good point - if there exists a comment that already provides the specific context for a downvote, I agree once is enough.  And I fully apologize up front for this smartypants addition: one could upvote the comment that explains the downvote B?/

Comment: @condiosluzverde "one could upvote the comment that explains the downvote B?" -- Possibly, for the same reasons one might upvote any other comment, regardless of whether the comment author or the comment voter have downvoted the question -- in particular, because the comment voter has, in general, no means of knowing whether the comment author has downvoted the question.

Comment: As the recipient of a down vote every once in a great while, the vast majority have no comment (this is from memory, no, I haven't checked!), and every time I think, "what did I do wrong? Or was it just some asshole? Maybe they didn't understand my problem?! If so, why didn't they say so?" ... In short, the recipient in that case FEELS BAD and DOES NOT KNOW WHY. And, I'd bet, it drives people away from the site. And that's bad no matter how righteous it may feel to do it.