# Can this question about comparing R dataframes be reopened, please?

Tags: discussion, reopen-closed

This question is quite helpful and rather relevant.

[How to compare two dataframes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978895/how-to-compare-two-dataframes)

It asks in clear, specific language about which functions are available for resolving a common, clear problem.

Including an example is entirely unneccessary for such a pure R language query that is in essence, 'What are the functions available to do a very specific task' question.

The best answer given is also concise and correct.

The person who closed this appears to have significant specialized knowledge, but not in the same area as the question's tags.

Comment: Not commenting on the actual quality of the post, since I'm not familiar with its tags, but don't take vote count or views as a measure of whether something should be open.

Comment: Why should it be reopened? Does it need a new answer? If not, it doesn't really make a difference. I mean, "closed" doesn't mean that it's gonna be deleted or something.

Comment: It was closed by a moderator, his name was "Kev" back then.  Overriding a moderator's decision, well, it will probably just collect more flags and force another moderator to deal with it.  Seems to be adequately answered, does it really need more guesses at what the OP intended?

Comment: @Floern A question shouldn't be closed/reopened based on whether or not the question already has good answers or not

Comment: @Rob that's true of course, but one could ask if it's worth the effort to reopen it if it's completely answered.

Comment: Why is this question being downvoted?

Comment: @leerssej downvoting on meta means disagreement, so they probably don't want to have that question reopened.

Comment: @leerssej On Meta, downvotes are often used to indicate disagreement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your request is sunk by how one of the answers starts

> Without an example I cannot be certain I understand what you want.

The problem is that the question, in modern closing vernacular, has no [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

There's no code, no data, just a general "How do I do X?" The answers are just guesses. Reopening it would just invite more guesses.

Comment: Nothing personal here, but those are not guesses. Those are actually the exact answers I was looking for when I formulated the query.  When I read that "without an example..." it was pretty clear that that poster didn't understand the subject well enough to answer but still thought it worth the time to fill up a page on the matter. I wouldn't side with that person (they were suggesting using for loops in R, and it took them 6 months to come back around and answer the question properly. Not that you could find that except for wading through all of the useless exampling he created.)

Comment: It just seems like it might be good to find a way to better enforce examples  when they are really necessary; especially when in such basic situations, where their inclusion is to the detriment of the question and answer quality.

Comment: @leerssej I don't think you know how many people post similar non-informational questions every day. I'm glad the answers helped you, but the question would be open if it contained a *specific* example

Answer (score 1):

### Only debugging style questions explicitly require code.

A how-to question is not a debugging question, so the "Debugging / no MCVE" close reason doesn't apply here. A how-to style question *can* be too broad or unclear if it does not contain example input or some kind of example code the demonstrates the problem, but that does not seem to be the case here.

### Is the question on-topic and answerable in its current state?

The top voted (and accepted) answer seems to adequately answer the question such that even I—having never used R—can easily see how it would achieve exactly what the OP is asking for even without example input. It does not appear to me that example input would have made the question any better, in fact I think it would have just been noise.

The question seems to be adequately on-topic and answerable in its current state, so I have voted to reopen it.

#### Related:

- [What's better: a question with no attempt or with an unfixable/irrelevant attempt?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338755/4639281)

Comment: "Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. **Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.**"

Comment: @Braiam thank you for highlighting a completely irrelevant piece of text. That question only asked one specific question, it contains enough detail to identify an adequate answer, and is reasonably limited in scope.

Answer (score -2):

As Mark Miller answer points, is difficult to measure exactly what kind of comparison the question asks, allowing for multiple interpretations that makes the question too broad.

1. Compare if all elements in dataframe A are exactly the same in the same position in df B, including column labels.
2. Print the difference between values on df A vs B.
3. Print only different cells but not the differences between them.

Each of those deserve its own Q&A pair. You could ask those questions instead.

Also you have to add:

> We'll need to know what the data frame contains: integers, numeric, factors, something else?

R guys seems to know that they need more to go on.