# Require clarification on the amount of research a question needs in order not to be closed

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, question-quality

The question that is prompting my request is [What is the difference between List.of and Arrays.asList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46579074/what-is-the-difference-between-list-of-and-arrays-aslist). This is the type of question that asks the most trivial question about a new feature, the type that are answered with just a little searching. Back in 2009 those question were considered acceptable, but not today ([How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)).

While some might not agree with such a strict view, even to the most forgiving person must ask themselves what kind of research the asker did. Currently the question is equivalent to

> I saw this *new thing* but instead of trying to read about it I wanted to be fed the answer.

The acceptable minimum is (should be?)

> I saw this *new thing*, read about it *there* and *this* is what I understand, but I don't understand *this point(s)*.

For those outside the Java realm, we have the JavaDocs which are the first and foremost information source. It is the official documentation by the language maintainers. They are integrated into our IDEs and pop with a mouse hover. It is unacceptable under any standard (educational, enterprise or otherwise) to not know of their existence or ignore them. If questions as the one under discussion are allowed, I might as well ask about every method and class in the language "what is ___ used for?".

My biggest surprise is the amount of upvotes the question received for being such a poor one. There are abundant similar questions which show no research and are downvoted drastically. Is it because this is a new language API that we're allowed to ask such questions? This is happening during a time where the community has voted that question quality is the first topic to improve ([Help set Q&A (TeamDAG) product development priorities](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354125/help-set-qa-teamdag-product-development-priorities)).

True, the question has been closed, but then reopened. The comments show weak reasoning for this:

> In my opinion, closing this question cuts too sharply against the intent or spirit of this forum. I vote to re-open since I feel others may have this same question, there are differences in implementation, and closing is too reflexively punitive.

and

> Javadocs do not mention the difference between implementation details of these two methods (like space consumption or performance). I think people would like to know these details too.

Others having the same questions is *not* a reopen reason. The point about difference in implementation is a technical one. The docs do mention differences in implementation, but not all of them. However, if these unmentioned differences are the reason for the question, then the question should have mentioned what's already written and ask specifically about these, as I've pointed out above. Ironically, the accepted and upvoted answer does not mention this point at all, and just reiterates the docs.

> Have voted to reopen it seconding the thought that a lot of things are detailed but the examples with their implementations are meant to be bringing value to the explanations which are(shouldn't be) not supposedly documented anytime.

Again, show what source you read, what you didn't understand about it and what code you wrote to test the behavior yourself. Then ask for examples about the parts you didn't understand. Am I allowed to ask for code examples for every method and class in the language?

I would like to clarify that conceptually I'm not against being able to ask any question one wants, I'm against the severe inconsistency that is displayed here. If I'm told here that this question is acceptable and deserving of its 30+ upvotes, I will *gladly* ask about 30 new features in Java 9 to which I can answer by copying the docs. I will also write a very long answer befitting of such a broad question.

Can I have a clarification about the question quality policy on SO?

Comment: i think it's because it's a new version. i got downvoted for similar questions i had only not about new versions. so it looks like this is the difference.

Comment: @gnat Relevant, thanks, but I'm asking about closure, not about votes. I personally don't find answers there that are valid answers to this question.

Comment: @CodeLღver See above.

Comment: We should bring back documentation at this rate.

Comment: related http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: Ironically this question shows a certain lack of research effort... ;)

Comment: ["We feel that the world is awash in questions, but not answers. Answers are the real unit of work in any Q&A system. Therefore, the only logical thing to do is to maximize the happiness and enjoyment of answerers.

If this means aggressively closing unworthy or uninteresting questions, so be it. **Without a community of people willing to answer questions, it really doesn't matter if there are questions at all, does it?**"](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/595/41104) The sad true is that there seems to be a community willing to answer those questions.

Comment: @Braiam Excellent, well, that's in contradiction to what the mod here said.

Comment: Yeah, people loves to have their rules but not understanding the meaning behind them.

Comment: @Braiam what you linked is not a rule, it is something that Jeff said six and a half years ago. It is not an all-encompassing statement, and contrary to your belief, that cannot be applied to every single discussion on meta. Frankly, I'm tired of seeing that parroted over and over again where it means nothing at all. In the same vein as that, if we close all the questions, there won't be anything to answer now will there?

Comment: @TinyGiant the fact that you need a rule to explain fairly basic human behavior, is very disturbing. People, in principle (and, hey, this is the nearest you get to a rule inside the realm of social science), act according to self interest. I've yet to see someone that invest resources into something that doesn't interest them, I'm not saying they don't exist, just very hard to come across. Have you seen one?

Comment: @Braiam As I've said before when you've brought this up in the past, I disagree. Plain and simple, I think you're wrong, I think it is a useless argument that only represents on side of a many sided equation, and I don't think that argument applies here, nor many of the other places that you have parroted it. I'm not going to argue about it anymore because there is no arguing with you, you don't listen to reason and you cannot possibly fathom that you're wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's better: a question with no attempt or with an unfixable/irrelevant attempt?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338755/4639281)

Comment: Jeff Atwood's statement, as cited by Braiam, is not at all in contradiction with what I said. I agree completely with Jeff on optimizing for pearls over sand. What I'm missing is why the cited question is so horrible and offensive to your sensibilities. Just because a question is basic does not make it bad. I have no problem with aggressively closing questions. I've probably cast more close votes than 95% of the users on this website.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Lack of research effort is not, and has never been, a reason to close a question.** Full stop.

It is, however, a reason that one might see fit to *downvote* a question. As the tooltip on the downvote arrow very clearly says:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

There is no corresponding close reason for lack of research effort, so if you're closing a question on that basis, you're doing it wrong. Your use of a custom close reason saying:

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is clearly stated in the docs.

was an abuse of that feature. Nowhere in [the list of things that make a question off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) (nor in the list [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)—yeah, this is confusingly split up onto multiple pages) will you find stated or implied "is clearly stated in the docs".

**The only time there might be some intersection between question closure and lack of prior research effort is when that lack of prior research effort makes the question *too broad* to be reasonably answered within the scope of a Stack Overflow answer.** In that case, since "too broad" is one of the close reasons, you can vote to close the question. But realize that you still aren't closing it because of the lack of research effort. You're closing it because it is too broad to be answered in our format. It just so happens that the *reason* it is too broad to be answered in our format is because the person who asked it didn't do enough prior research to narrow down their question. There are plenty of other cases where exhaustively-researched questions might be too broad and thus closed.

As [xenteros points out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357501), there are sections in the Help Center and Q&A on Meta that recommend doing research before asking a question. There are plenty of good reasons for this, and I'm not trying to diminish the relevance of the advice. As I pointed out above, lack of research effort is still a reason to downvote a question, it's a reason a question might tend to be off-topic for another reason, and it's certainly a reason why a question might be a duplicate. But lack of research effort *alone* does not make a question off-topic.

Let's assume for a moment that it did. What would happen? Carried to its logical conclusion, this would render *all* questions off-topic, since every question can be answered with a sufficient amount of research effort, even if the answer had not previously been known to humanity and you had to discover it for the first time (which is what researchers actually do). So obviously this is silly. It is also self-defeating. Our goal is to be an encyclopedia of high-quality answers to the long-tail of programming questions.

On the other hand, **if you're looking for an official(-ish) sanction to go ask a question about each of the features of Java 9, you won't find it from me. I think you and I both know that's pretty ridiculous.** Use some common sense. Is the question clear and relevant? Does it fit within the scope defined in the Help Center? Would other professional or enthusiast programmers find its answer(s) to be useful? Those are our question quality standards.

For what it's worth, **I don't see anything wrong with [the question motivating this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46579074/what-is-the-difference-between-list-of-and-arrays-aslist)**. I think it's a perfectly valid question, it looks like something that would probably be useful to other professional and enthusiast programmers, and the answers it's accumulated are in keeping with our mission of making the Internet a better, more-informed place. (Although I couldn't help but notice that *neither* of the answers cites the official documentation. If this is as clearly covered there as you claim, then that's kind of odd, isn't it?)

I'm not going to comment on whether the question "deserves" 30–40 upvotes. I find this notion of desert pretty silly. There's no objective standard for how many votes a question deserves. That's why voting is an individual privilege. A question deserves the score that it gets after the community votes freely on it.

Comment: "*lack of research effort alone does not make a question off-topic. Let's assume for a moment that it did. What would happen? Carried to its logical conclusion, this would render all questions off-topic*" That's not the logical conclusion for this statement, it's the logical conclusion for "lack of all possible research...". The conclusion of "lack of [any/some] research" is far less dramatic.

Comment: *"Although I couldn't help but notice that neither of the answers cites the official documentation. If this is as clearly covered there as you claim, then that's kind of odd, isn't it?"* It is, and fact is that the writer of the accepted answer (with 70+ upvotes currently)  admitted that his answer is lacking. Isn't that odd?

Comment: How do you know that the person didn't perform any/some research? That cannot be measured objectively, so it cannot be a close reason. Is it odd that someone admitted their answer is lacking? Not really. Why haven't you written a better one?

Comment: I know that they didn't post anything showing they did *any* research, and it they did do the minimum they wouldn't have asked the question as it is. I haven't written a better answer (or asked that question myself over a year ago when I learned about this in early releases) because I think it's a bad question (I said that in the last paragraph). However, since you changed what I knew about the accepted quality of questions about 120 degrees I will be sure to write more Q&A of this quality.

Comment: Also, I think that you automatically get the accepted answer on this as a mod, but I'll wait to see if others want to chime in.

Comment: While I mostly agree with the *lack of research not being a reason to close a question* point, unfortunately, this is not the behavior I see trying to be enforced by a lot of users. Ultimately, I hold on to the hope that I'm not the only one being annoyed by all those questions getting upvoted/closed/left open for whatever unicorn's black magic reasons...

Comment: There, I answered as promised.

Comment: _Lack of research effort is not, and has never been, a reason to close a question._  - that approach is exactly a reason why there are posts about _quality dropping_ ... Seriously. Decide whether you want to [promote crap](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment221053_261593) or [try to keep the quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/4241435). Nevertheless, the overall level of hypocrisy will soon exceed JonSkeet's reputation  :-)

Comment: @Skipper No, that is not why there are posts about question quality dropping. The reason there are posts about question quality dropping is because low quality questions are being asked. The question being discussed here is *not* low quality. It is clear, useful, relevant, and on-topic.

Comment: "clear, useful, relevant", for whom? Remember: votes are just a proxy for other things, but they don't necessarily indicate those things.

Comment: @Gall That is why we must be ever-vigilant in how we interact with the site and other users. Education is key, and the problem is not a problem that will be solved over night. We need to work together to change close voting culture here on Stack Overflow, and bring it up to the standards we hold so dear.

Comment: “*Lack of research effort […] has never been, a reason to close a question*”— well [“Lacks Minimal Understanding” *has been*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/257868/2711488) a close reason and that included those who were not even trying…

Comment: @Holger That reason was removed *precisely because* people were misusing it as a close reason for questions that did not show research effort.

Answer (score 3):

There is a really nice article in the help center. You can link to it by simply adding `[ask]` in a comment to the question. It's [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Let me quote:

> ## Search, and research
>
> ...and keep track of what you find. Even if you don't find a useful
> answer elsewhere on the site, **including links to related questions
> that haven't helped can help others** in understanding how your question
> is different from the rest.

So basically the community encourages people to include the research in questions already.

Answer (score 0):

> Require clarification on the amount of research a question needs in order not to be closed.

As the answer by Cody Gray already pointed out, a lack of research is not explicitly a close reason. However, a question lacking any research might get closed for other reasons (after all people are free with their close votes and there might not be enough re-open votes happening). A minimal amount of research (something like a single sentence saying you thought it could be solved by [insert some bogus here] but it didn't work out) should, in my experience, be sufficient to ensure a question lacking research remains open.

Going deeper:

A lack of research warrants a downvote. But then, where is the difference between a heavily downvoted (and therefore removed) question and a closed question? Both mean, for all practical purposes, a much less likely answering of the question. Effectively, close voting acts like downvoting on steroids.

That means, that in order to avoid close- or downvotes one should present an awful lot of research actually. And that would indeed be nice, but almost nobody ever does it. Why?

Because most people are lazy and get away with it. If you are lazy and not stupid you just fake a sufficient amount of research that covers the lack of research. Just play stupid. Nobody (except those who know you) knows if you truly are so inapt to not being able to deliver complete and high quality research on a topic. Nobody can really tell the difference and the community wants to answer your question anyway and does not (currently) require a scrupulously high amount of research or otherwise they don't even start answering your question. That's just not how it is. You are likely to get away (get positive score and answers) to questions showing only minimal (might even be all faked) research.

Now my question: Where is the problem actually? How bad is it really that some rather easy to answer questions of lazy people get upvotes and answers?

Comment: I think the problem is that that question and answer got an **absurd** amount of upvotes. If they would've gotten single digit upvotes like other question and answers of similar quality that are not about Java 9 no one would've cared. People are trying to make it about content but probably what really bothers them is the huge amount of unjustified upvotes they got. At least I'm willing to admit that that's what bothers me.

Comment: That single bogus sentence you mentioned should not even be included in a question because it's just noise. If it's inclusion magically makes the question on-topic, then the question was never off-topic to begin with. Nobody really cares about your bogus attempts to solve the problem, and everybody lies anyway. That's why topicality (and, indeed, quality) is not determined by the amount of research effort. It's a *prima facie* metric applied to the question itself.

Comment: Presenting an exhaustive compendium of your prior research is actually a *terrible* thing. Good questions are concise and get to the point quickly. Nobody wants to read a detailed history of your failures. They just want to know what the problem is. People fixate on "research effort" because they're tired of code dumps and task dumps. The problem with those is not that the person didn't do any research. They wouldn't be on-topic even if they *had* done research. These are just bad  questions. In fact, they're *not even questions*. To fix the quality problem, we must focus on the right problem.