# First post review

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I had a first-post-review test and I failed... However, I think the post wasn't following the guidelines, so I commented on the question:

[Haskell - manipulating/extending an ADT that isn’t under your control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47274139/haskell-manipulating-extending-an-adt-that-isn-t-under-your-control)

> Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For
>   help with this, read How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable
>   example. If it is possible to create a live example of the problem
>   that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or
>   http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also include the code in your
>   question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links
>   may break over time.

The author of the question only linked to the question.

I get that these tests are generated, but the link and no code blocks should have first-post-reviewers help the first-posters to improve the quality of their posts...

Comment: Relevant: [Only debugging style questions explicitly require code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338846/4639281). That is not a debugging question, and your comment looks entirely unhelpful even if well intentioned. I don't pretend to know anything about Haskell, but from reading the question and the answers, it seems that what is behind the link is irrelevant, and the question and answers are nicely self contained. If anything, the question could do with some removal of fluff (and possibly the off-site reference itself), but I would leave that to the Haskell community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, good questions should include all relevant information needed to answer them within the question itself.  Links to external sites are liable to [rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) sooner or later, which is why they should not be relied on to convey essential information.

That said, I'm not personally familiar enough with Haskell to tell if the [linked definition](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-types/blob/f1278603a4766f32b8375de84b8581f4bb1e665a/Text/Pandoc/Definition.hs#L212) in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47274139/haskell-manipulating-extending-an-adt-that-isn-t-under-your-control) is really needed to make sense of it, or whether it's just an illustrative but ultimately non-essential example.  If the latter, then having it behind a link is acceptable, since even if the link rots, it can just be replaced or removed.

Anyway, if you feel that the question is not sufficiently exemplary for an audit, you can downvote it.  That should make it ineligible to be chosen for future audits.

(FWIW, that question has [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47274139/timeline) been used as an audit 12 times so far.  All of the previous audits were successfully passed.)