# What's wrong with my post? How can I improve?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, asking-questions, new-users

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post [Downsize page content as page gets smallerCS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50633504/downsize-page-content-as-page-gets-smallercs):

[image: Downsize page content as page gets smallerCS]

I'm new to Stack Overflow and I can't say for sure that it's been a completely amazing experience. Now, I might have done something wrong in the above example, but I think it is pretty clear that in the post above, people mostly spent their time down voting my post rather than actually providing an answer, or better yet, explaining what I exactly did wrong.

Why was this received so badly by the Stack Overflow community?

Comment: Apparently this post got my other one downvoted more.



Well played Stack community, I'm switching to Reddit as it seems more of an inviting and casual environment

Comment: I'm not one of the downvoters, but the problem is that at Stack Overflow we don't give _pointers_. We are here to write **specific** answers to **specific** questions. You pretty much always need to show us what you've tried or what research you've done. Reading a website's guidelines is very important before you start using it (Reddit has guidelines as well, though they are not as strict which therefore makes it SEEM more "inviting"). Please refer to the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information.

Comment: You are right that Reddit is better for questions like this; it's a very general question inviting just any kind of answer, perhaps a link to a guide, or some terms to search for, or if someone really wants to go for it, a full fledged tutorial. None of these are things Stack Overflow is good at. The time to come to Stack Overflow would be after you have started coding or if you are reviewing some instructions and you have a specific question about how something works or how to fix an error you are having and are unable to resolve by your own research.

Comment: @DogeDude : No problem. The reason Stack Overflow has such strict guidelines is mainly for _quality control_. SO strives to build an "internet library" where it should be easy to find high-quality questions and answers. By filtering questions that have already been answered, questions that are unclear and questions that can have _too many_ or _too long_ answers, we are left with the questions and answers of higher actual quality and "educativeness".

Comment: That questions is just too broad. Including what you tried or research would not have helped your question at all. You need to break your problem down into smaller well-defined problems.

Comment: @TinyGiant : If the OP would would've posted what he/she had tried (or researched) and **explained why that didn't work**, that would have been a small(er) and more well-defined problem.

Comment: @VisualVincent I think Tiny's point here was that If you do that, then the question isn't a 'I tried nothing and am all out of ideas'. It becomes a question about 'in trying to achieve X, I am doing Y, and it gives me G instead of Z'

Comment: @Patrice : I know about the XY problem, but this is partly also what debugging questions are about.

Comment: @Visual I agree there. What I mean is that I think you and tiny are saying the same thing :p

Comment: @Patrice : You are probably right. Guess the issue was that I didn't include "and describe what went wrong" in my initial comment (however it was my intention), which might have been why this baffled me.

Comment: It would be useful to write up a clear answer for the OP and other new users landing on the site.

Comment: @Visual I disagree. That would only turn an overly broad how-to question into an overly useless debugging question. It's much better to break the problem down into smaller problems and solve each separately. FYI what Patrice was referring to would not be an XY question. An XY question is when someone really wanted to ask about X but they've been conditioned into the false belief that all how to questions are off topic and therefore they should try and fail horribly without any guidance ending up completely in the wrong direction until they are thoroughly confused and finally ask how to fix Y.

Comment: ... at which point they are told that their code makes no sense whatsoever and they should have just asked X in the first place, by the same people that would tell them that asking about X without first trying and failing horribly would be off topic.

Comment: @TinyGiant : _"That would only turn an overly broad how-to question into an overly useless debugging question"_ - Well I disagree. You are allowed to ask debugging questions at Stack Overflow, even though they might be helpful only to you. _Not all_ questions have to be perfect and be something that will help many others (we strive for it, but we still allow minor deviations). Same goes for homework questions - not all of them are very advanced and will not help many others than the OP.

Comment: @TinyGiant : If we _didn't_ allow these kinds of deviations then Stack Overflow wouldn't be a Q&A site at all. It would literally just be a library where we produce knowledge, and those that weren't "smart enough" wouldn't be able to get any help. This wouldn't be so good for the site's reputation.

Comment: @VisualVincent you misunderstand me. At no point did I say that debugging questions were off topic. I said that they tend to be overly useless and localized. My point is that contrary to popular belief (and your suggestion that all questions are required to include an attempt which is false) how to questions _are_ on topic. The specific problem with this how to question is not that it doesn't include code, but that it is plainly Too Broad. Plain and simple. Code would not have helped narrow down this how-to question, it would have transformed it into a useless debugging question.

Comment: @VisualVincent I recommend reading [What's better: a question with no attempt or with an unfixable/irrelevant attempt?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338846/4639281)

Comment: @TinyGiant : _`and your suggestion that all questions are required to include an attempt which is false`_ - But specifically quoting the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour): _"Don't ask about... Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for **(show your work!)**"_. However I did actually say that you **pretty much** always had to include your attempts. That is not the same as _always_.

Comment: @TinyGiant : _"I said that they tend to be overly useless and localized"_ - True, but as I said we still allow that. You don't _have_ to ask a question that will be helpful to millions of people, even though we strive for them to be as widely helpful as possible. This still is a Q&A site, which means we are still here to answer people's questions _(continuation in next comment)_.

Comment: @TinyGiant : _"Code would not have helped narrow down this how-to question, it would have transformed it into a useless debugging question."_ - Not code by itself, of course. But with code (and perhaps research) that at least shows a genuine effort _combined with_ an explanation of what is happening versus what he/she wants to achieve _would_ have narrowed it down since he/she would then (hopefully) be halfway there.

Comment: @TinyGiant : (Running out of comment space) Also bare in mind that in my initial comment I actually said _"what you've tried or **what research you've done**"_. I wasn't explicitly saying that he/she has to show _code_, but something that proves that he/she's made a _**genuine**_ effort, which likely would have narrowed the problem down either by making us understand what he/she is trying to achieve or understand what [_"haven't helped"_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to identify what the OP is looking for (the latter is more unlikely to happen, but still possible).

Comment: @VisualVincent you're still missing what I'm saying entirely. I didn't say that useless debugging questions were allowed, I said they're useless. Re the help center: there's a difference between not trying to find the answer at all, and not having tried and failed horribly before asking. Ultimately neither research effort or coding effort are **required** for how to questions. For most how to questions, any code included is just noise. Pointing at things youve looked at that were similar but didnt help can help in narrowing down how to questions but again not required.

Comment: The problem with this question is that it was just too broad. No ifs ands or buts. Including code would not have made this a better question, nor would have helped anyone involved. It would just be a whole bunch of effort wasted. What _would_ actually help would be to break down the problem into smaller problems and solve each separately. That would be more useful and much less wasteful for everyone involved.

Comment: @TinyGiant : _"there's a difference between not trying to find the answer at all, and not having tried and failed horribly before asking"_ - I understand what you are saying, but I don't understand your point with this sentence? -- _"Ultimately neither research effort or coding effort are **required** for how to questions"_ - I know. That's why I said "pretty much always" (generalized for all types of questions). :)

Comment: _"For **most** how to questions, any code included is just noise"_ - I can partly agree, but I'd say it depends on the situation. _Most_ how to-questions that _I've seen_ in the `vb.net` tag have (or could have) benefitted from showing some code or other form of effort. Infact they usually won't get help if they don't. Though I guess you and I are probably used to seeing different kinds of questions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'll codify as an answer what I think the main issue is.

You want us to **teach** you.  Stack Overflow isn't here to **teach**.  It's here to **help**.

Your question didn't leave us anything in which we could readily *help* you with.  There are *numerous* ways to do what you're asking, and explaining one or two would require a lot of time and energy on our part.

We're not built to **teach** you on these concepts, we're built to **help** you through them.

If you came back explaining that you had a problem with your code that did something close to what you were looking for - resizing images and making the layout reactive with a smaller window frame - then we could **help**.  Until then...your best option right now is to look into tutorials or trainings which would teach you this concept.

Comment: Great answer! Though I find this part a little peculiar: _"You want us to teach you. Stack Overflow isn't here to teach. It's here to help."_ - I'd say that SO is here to both help _**and**_ teach. The difference lies within how one defines _"teach"_. In most cases we do teach the OPs something they didn't know before, and we try and usually want to do that as well. However we are not their _teachers_ and thus will not go through it step-by-step for them.

Comment: @VisualVincent:  For the *very reason* that everyone's definition of "teach" radically diverges, it's easier in my mind to quantify what we're doing as "help".  We're not giving them a full-blown course on the technology they're having trouble with, nor are we providing them a detailed tutorial.  We're giving them an example; a hand; some help.  Conflating the two together leads to situations in which questions which *really* should be shut down because they're too broad aren't, because people believe that they should be taught instead of simply helped.

Comment: That's a very interesting point!

Comment: yep that's a problem on the site, people are, unwittingly, looking for tutors or coaches and we can't do that.