# How can I ask a question without it getting closed when I clearly followed the guidelines?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I recently asked a question and it was marked as off topic. I wrote the question while reviewing the "[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" and "[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" references.

The person who wrote the minimal example reference was one of the people who marked is as off topic. This is the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51500466/how-to-work-around-needing-to-inherit-from-2-already-defined-classes-in-c-sharp?noredirect=1#comment89969270_51500466)

My question states what my objective is in the first paragraph, how the code will be used in the second paragraph, the rest describes the problem.

I posted all of the code needed to reproduce the problem as stated in the guidelines. If someone needed to reproduce the issue, they could do it with the code that is there. But I believe most who can answer the question would not need to try to reproduce it.

My description clearly stated what the issue is, I did not post a "Why doesn't this work?", I know why, I included a line stating why it doesn't work.

I posted this question in the section related to C# and XAML. It is being written in C#, and will be referenced in both C# and XAML. Which was clear in describing how it would be used.

My question was clear in the solution I was looking for.

My only assumption is that those who marked it did not bother to read the question. Since there is no method to contact anyone on the page for clarification the question will go unanswered.

Without the mods adding any comments as to how a question can be fixed, an issue such as mine may never be answered (After several hours of searching it may be impossible to do).

I really do need an answer to the question I asked, but I followed all of the guidelines when asking it, and it was flagged. I can't think of another way to ask the question, without purposely violating the guidelines, as I don't know what else to do or try.

So I believe the question meets the guidelines, yet it's marked that it doesn't. How can I rewrite it to meet the guidelines?

Comment: While I'm not sure on the closure itself, I haven't fully read through/parsed the question yet... The fact one of the close voters chose to close for "wrong assumptions" rather than answer _clarifying and correcting_ that wrong assumption concerns me... It's a wrong assumption I and several of my friends made when we were newer programmers, which insinuates it might be a common misunderstanding. Hence, it would be useful to answer. (Besides, making a wrong assumption doesn't make a post off-topic, unless something changed in the past day or two. =/)

Comment: Why didn't you react to the two comments posted on your question? That might have helped to make it more clear.

Comment: @Kendra Read the comment above it.  They apparently didn't feel the need to repeat it.

Comment: @Servy Which _still_ should have been (in the general sense, not this one when the question did meet criteria to be closed) an answer, not a comment, and _still_ isn't a reason to close the question. Being wrong is not a close reason. (After reading the question, I'm not really arguing with the rest of the close votes, and you've nicely outlined why in your answer. Just that _particular_ close vote reason.)

Comment: @Kendra Sure, I agree that it's not a good description of why the question isn't answerable.  Hence why I used a different reason myself.

Comment: A question being based on a misguided or even completely incorrect premise has never been a reason to close a question. It _has_ always been a reason  to _answer_.

Comment: @TinyGiant you can also look at the question differently - it already contains answer as code, so it is self-answered question with answer incorrectly posted as part of the question... The code shown in the post clearly is not MCVE to the question asked - maybe it should be removed from the post (but it still leave question unclear)... I like "missing MCVE" reason more as it a bit more actionable.

Comment: Also since I have the goldhammer and I'm not nice I'd close that question as duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178333/multiple-inheritance-in-c-sharp (again, this is not nice, so I'm making SO better by trying not to visit it or vote there).

Comment: @Alexei It doesn't look like a debugging question to me. It looks like a how-to style question based on a misconception of the language. I'm not a C#, XAML, or MVVM guy, but if I understand correctly the misconception is _"But it is not possible to inherit from 2 different classes."_, and the (terse) answer to the question is _"INotifyPropertyChanged is an interface, you can implement asw many of those as you like." [sic]_.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. Although it is stated that I made the wrong assumption the reason given for closing the question was "Off-topic" I find this confusing, as other than the single comment I only see "off-topic". I feel the system is lacking in the fact that I made a wrong assumption, and I did not know that before the topic was closed. I asked this questions so that I could do better in the future and possibly it would help others, I'm not sure why that warranted all of the down-votes.

Answer (score 25):

> My question states what my objective is in the first paragraph

Yep.

> how the code will be used in the second paragraph

Still going good

> the rest describes the problem.

Here's where you ran into trouble.  You didn't say what problem you were having with the code that you provided.  You just said what you want to do, posted some code, and said nothing about why that code doesn't work.

> I posted all of the code needed to reproduce the problem as stated in the guidelines.

No.  You neither stated what problems it has, nor does it reproduce whatever problems you claim it has.

The code of course won't compile, because you haven't defined the base class, and you're missing an implementation.  The only problems with that code are not problems that you've brought up at all.

> If someone needed to reproduce the issue, they could do it with the code that is there.

No, they can't.

> But I believe most who can answer the question would not need to try to reproduce it.

Your question makes no sense.  So...no.

> My description clearly stated what the issue is

You claim that your issue is that you can't inherit from two classes, but then provided a very incomplete code sample that *doesn't try to inherit from two classes*.  So, no, you didn't clearly state what the issue is.

> I did not post a "Why doesn't this work?", I know why, I included a line stating why it doesn't work.

But that statement is demonstrably false.  As incomplete as your code sample is, it *is* complete enough to know that that statement isn't true.

> My question was clear in the solution I was looking for.

But not in what problem you had accomplishing it.

> My only assumption is that those who marked it did not bother to read the question. Since there is no method to contact anyone on the page for clarification the question will go unanswered.

Well I voted to close it, and I read it (both before voting to close, and again when writing this answer), so I can confirm that this assumption is false.

As for contacting people, you could have replied to either of the two commentors, both of which voted to close the question.

> Without the mods adding any comments as to how a question can be fixed, an issue such as mine may never be answered (After several hours of searching it may be impossible to do).

You know what you need to do.  It's in the close reason.  Provide a description of what isn't working, and a code sample that replicates that exact description when run/compiled.

> I really do need an answer to the question I asked

That doesn't really matter.  The question either merits closure or it doesn't.  If anything, this should motivate you to fix the problems with your questions, read the feedback given to you (you had comments within *seconds* telling you about the problems with your example).

> I can't think of another way to ask the question

Describe, specifically, what isn't working about your solution.  Provide an actual error message or exception message (or detailed description of erroneous behavior).  Then provide code that, when run, produces exactly the same problem that you described.

> So I believe the question meets the guidelines, yet it's marked that it doesn't. How can I rewrite it to meet the guidelines?

Describe, specifically, what isn't working about your solution.  Provide an actual error message or exception message (or detailed description of erroneous behavior).  Then provide code that, when run, produces exactly the same problem that you described.

Comment: _how to work around needing wings to fly from London to New York_ -- I want to fly from London to New York. For that I need a pair of wings that would let me fly from London to New York. I found a pair of angel wings in a local theater but these don't fly. How do I work around this?

Comment: @gnat A better analogy would be. "I need to get from London to New York.  I bought this plane ticket for a flight from London to New York.  Humans don't have wings and can't fly unaided.  What do I do now?  How can I use my plane ticket to get to New York given that humans don't have wings?"

Comment: [What's a plane?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261859/839601)

Comment: @gnat [An up goer](https://xkcd.com/1133/).

Answer (score 8):

Servy's answer [categorically responds to the points you make](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/371515/1079354), but I wanted to offer a more terse answer, and more importantly, focus on one aspect.

> My question was clear in the solution I was looking for.

The ultimate goal is that you want to avoid multiple inheritance.  No code in the world can illustrate that problem more succinctly than the non-code you had before it.

> In order to allow the xaml access, my class needs to inherit from MarkupExtension, in order to update the data that is bound to my class needs to inherit from INotifyPropertyChanged.

The problem with a question like this is, it's *highly* subjective.  I believe it was a fool's errand to try and generate an MCVE for this since there's no value for it, and I'm sorry that you were sent on such an errand.  **However**, the real issue is that the crux of your question is too broad.  The bare-bones solution is [illustrated in an OO principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance), but applying that to your specific issue would require us to [take considerable effort to explain](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/368938/1079354) it all to you at once.

Answer (score 5):

You claim "it is not possible to inherit from 2 different classes" as problem you have but question does not have MCVE for *that problem*. As result question correctly closed as missing MCVE. Optionally question could be downvoted for not researching difference between classes and interfaces or not reading about https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+multiple+inheritance...

Indeed question contains code, but there is only one class and such code would compile just fine.

```
public class Manager : MarkupExtension, INotifyPropertyChanged
{ ... }
```

I'm not sure which way your question should be edited but in current state I don't think it can be answered.