# Is this question considered on-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

[How do I clear the content of a div using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450593/how-do-i-clear-the-content-of-a-div-using-javascript)

Yes, it's a "specific programming problem" involving "a software algorithm" and definitely "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development". But it shows zero effort - it's seriously the epitome of "just Google it" - and my concern is that if we allow this sort of no-effort question, more specific "gimme teh codez" questions will come to be seen as on-topic.

So yea or nay?

Comment: "asked Aug 10 '10" At that moment, rules were a lot more loose, we didn't knew what quality looked like. We learned something and then unlearned it.

Comment: It was reopened 30 mins ago after being closed since 2012

Comment: If you want to destroy this question, you will have to destroy a large part of the most upvoted and useful question in SO. "just Google it" doesn't apply here, because those questions are the ones you get from google search. This question has been "viewed 304,385 times", this is from google search.

Comment: We don't need to *destroy* it but it doesn't need to be open either. It doesn't need more answers and it doesn't serve as a good example.

Comment: @ivarni Once it is closed, people can cast delete vote on it. One day it might be deleted silently. See example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596108/how-do-i-change-my-password-in-linux

Comment: Sure, you can easily google it today.  To find that exact question back, first hit when you query "javascript clear content of div".  Three hundred thousand other programmers did as well.  Maybe a javascript programmer's life was more difficult in 2010, it is not unlikely.  It isn't anymore, partly thanks to SO :)  Asking such a question today and not creating a duplicate is much more difficult.  Yay.

Comment: @liliscent when people throw re-open votes at it it eventually ends up here were a very likely outcome is that it gets deleted as a result from the attention it gets when someone comes around later asking *"why is **this** question ok when **mine** was closed"*. It was doing just fine for 4 years. I'll agree that some people can be a bit careless with their delete-votes but that doesn't mean we should also be careless with reopen votes in my opinion.

Comment: @ivarni Someone posted it on reddit's /r/programming and it got reopen-brigaded: https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/8y7k2e/how_do_i_clear_the_content_of_a_div_using/

Comment: Yes it was a lazy question. Yes the author gained a lot of reputation just because (s)he didn't bother to search. But that was a loong time ago and now this QA is a useful reference for developers. So can't we just freeze it and stop fighting about it?

Comment: Hmm, no, reddit users can't reopen questions.  Only SO users can do that.  Not that it is hard to find them, they tend to care about Q+A that helped 300K programmers.  Or they just don't want anybody to ask that question again.

Comment: The question has been locked and put on hold.

Comment: Perfect, then it will stay around and keep being useful while also stop getting bumped and showing up in review queues. Win-win.

Comment: I am really confused why this question would be closed again. It seems entirely on-topic, succinctly stated, and valuable for people coming from Google. I understand why the *old* variant was closed, but the edits since have fixed all that.

Comment: I disagree with the closure, too. The question (while open) received only two answers with a couple of lines. If we can call this too broad then what isn't? If the question shows zero effort and you find it *not useful*, then downvote. This is no reason to close.

Comment: @HansPassant But Stack Overflow users do browse reddit.

Comment: Also, I forgot that posting this question would Meta Effect it, which was absolutely the opposite of my intention. :(

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, but I thought the point of StackOverflow was to *be* the top Google result for questions like this, instead of ExpertsExchange. If it's too broad, perhaps revert the edits that removed the details from the question?

Comment: @liliscent FYI questions that gather delete votes or are recently deleted (and vice versa with undelete votes) are tracked and listed at the [10k tools](https://stackoverflow.com/tools) page. There are also users who run SEDE scripts looking for these on occasion, and at least one moderator pledged during their election to monitor recently deleted questions to make sure no gems slipped through the cracks. On top of that, there's the 'favorite question' feature, which for 10k+ users will still be visible on the favorites list, *and* show up as deleted. Deleted Qs are never *truly* gone.

Comment: @liliscent The "how to change my password in Linux" question you shared as an example is rightfully closed and deleted because it's completely off-topic. There are no doubt identical questions on both the Linux SE site and Superuser.

Comment: See also, [What's better: a question with no attempt or with an unfixable/irrelevant attempt?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338846/4639281)

Comment: After the result of "Just googling it" I would like to see a suggestion of a stackoverflow link. So I suggest that this question to be asked.

Comment: Searched for the subject question, got the answer, came to see what all the fuss was about in meta. My two cents. Is this site ONLY for information that can't be found elsewhere? If so, then sure, delete it. But every day there are people learning (and in my case forgetting) how to work with javascript. I appreciate googling something and seeing links to this site because it has such good answers. Sure, mozilla and W3 schools has good documentation, but I always appreciate seeing the plethora of answers and the discussion about various approaches.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The post in question has since been closed and given a historical lock by Samuel Liew.

Aside from that, the question itself is actually on-topic and not problematic, assuming it is not a duplicate of an older or better question. The powers that be have regularly stated that simple/basic questions are OK here so long as they fit the requirements (programming question, specific, answerable, not a duplicate, not primarily opinion-based, etc.). Questions do not have to be stellar or interesting or niche to be allowed here.

Comment: Well, questions did not have to be interesting back in 2010.  Today with so many fewer contributors adding interesting answers it is a different problem.

Comment: @Hans there's a difference between what makes a question acceptable topically, and what makes contributors _want_ to answer a question. Sure I only want to answer interesting Questions, but I don't vote to close questions just because I don't want to answer them. If it isn't interesting enough for anyone to answer, is that really a problem? The point of closing questions is to prevent answers after all.

Comment: The answers to the post in question do not mention the most efficient and up-to-date method, `element.replaceChildren()`. The post could be improved but is locked.