# Why is this question on hold?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

I just saw [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53269860/tolerance-for-ipopt-optimizer) that has been put on hold for being unclear. However, it is a very clear question for people who use the question's only tag. I fear that it has been put on hold by people who don't work with the library, which could seem very complex for non-users of optimization and operational management.

Am I right to question the closure? What can someone using a tag of a complex library do to avoid being misunderstood by people who don't work with the library?

Comment: Generally, arguing that the closers don't understand the topic space isn't going to fly.  You'd be much better off trying to edit your question and making it clearer.  For other questions, you can suggest edits to try to make it clearer, but you need to ensure you're not adding things not mentioned, or changing intent.

Comment: Then, would explaining and giving definitions of terms help for this particular case?

Comment: Not really.  There's been no context provided, so explaining terms won't make the question any clearer.

Comment: Thanks, I know you can't talk for the closer, but it is hard for me to understand how was this question unclear. Having their view on it would have helped.

Comment: I've pinged the close voters, I assume some of them will comment here or leave an answer. It was reported in SOCVR by FireAlarm: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/90230?m=44546279#44546279

Comment: To me, it sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  The asker has a problem, and assumes the solution is to lower the tolerance of the package, so they asks about that.  We have no idea what they're trying to do, nor what the root problem is, just what they're trying to get the solution to be.  It'd be much clearer (and useful for everybody) if we knew what the problem they're attempting to solve is.

Comment: As posted, this question is both too broad _and_ unclear and this has nothing to do with whether one uses the library. You can avoid being misunderstood by reading [ask].

Comment: @PearlySpencer I disagree there; this is not broad. He wants to change a single parameter in a built-in function. That's highly specific. Admittedly the OP could've done more research and shown what they tried, but this is not broad, nor unclear, and that's without me knowing a thing about the library. There's hardly anything to misunderstand here, it's "How do I change *foo*'s *bar*-parameter".

Comment: Ok, while I can't provide the asker's context for them, I can see that I have to be extra careful while posting about complex librairies for myself, to avoid that kind of confusion.

Comment: @Madhur it's not a debugging question, no reproduction is neccessary. It's a how-to question, and those questions [do not explicitly require code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338846/4639281). Regardless, that isn't the reason used for this question's closure, but rather _"unclear what you're asking"_. It looks fairly clear to me, but I have no experience in the technology at hand.

Comment: @Adriaan I respectfully disagree. But the good news is that we agree that we disagree!

Comment: Future googlers will query for "pyomo change tolerance".  And find the one-and-only SO answer from Bethany.  If it doesn't get deleted.  If it does it is not completely disastrous, there is a Pyomo forum question that talks about it as well.  Forums being the place to get obscure answers, how's that for a complete reversal.  But at least the visitors know the subject.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I voted to close as unclear, because it's not clear what the question really wants.

The [ipopt solver](https://projects.coin-or.org/Ipopt) has the [following 10 tolerance settings](https://www.coin-or.org/Ipopt/documentation/node42.html#SECTION000112010000000000000):

- `tol`
- `dual_inf_tol`
- `constr_viol_tol`
- `compl_inf_tol`
- `acceptable_tol`
- `acceptable_constr_viol_tol`
- `acceptable_dual_inf_tol`
- `acceptable_compl_inf_tol`
- `acceptable_obj_change_tol`
- `diverging_iterates_tol`

As the question is currently written, it's impossible to determine what the user is really asking about. They *probably* are asking about `tol`, but thinking that would just be an educated guess. We should not need to *guess*.

The alternative is to assume that they are asking about all of the settings. In that case they are basically asking for a tutorial on what those various settings mean, how to use them, and when to use them, which is *too broad*.

Comment: Ghe, so this is basically turned around: if you know nothing about the library all you can do is downvote because of a lack of research, whereas if you do know the library, you'd have voted to close. Nice reasoning.

Comment: Thanks to highlight the fact that it was because you had to guess what tolerance it was about. I think, if it has been me, I would first have asked more details to the asker, since he might not have realized that the "tolerance" term was not giving enough details on what kind of tolerance they wanted to adjust.

Comment: @V.Brunelle Which is exactly why it's closed as unclear.

Comment: And perhaps, inputs to askers on what is unclear should have been done. What is this reputation used for if you can't comment questions to ask for improvements?

Comment: You can.  There's no need to, though; we prefer energy to be spent on questions that are already answerable.  That's what the close reason is for; to explain what's wrong with it.  But until that happens, it certainly should be closed.

Comment: Then, it appears to me that if I want serious expert discussions on the subject, I have to stop coming to SO. If you want SO to be turned into an Excel formula forum, turning down serious question with a no effort vote to close on questions that you don't understand is the way to go.

Comment: And here I thought we were making headway.  Sad to see that you still think the voters didn't understand.  Well, can't change that.  Best I can do is re-iterate that SO isn't a forum, isn't trying to be one, and that we have specific quality standards that all posts must meet.

Comment: @V.Brunelle In an ideal world, the OP would have come back to clarify their question, either in as a result of the closure or in response to a comment asking for such clarification. The OP has visited the  site since the closure, so could have already provided clarification, or a comment asking what's not clear, etc. A comment asking for specific things to be clarified might have been beneficial. You would have been just as welcome as anyone else to leave a comment asking the OP for specific clarification.

Comment: However, in my experience, it is very, very rare for a user to clarify their question, at all, after they've received an answer which gives them a solution to the most probable issue (this answer also, by extension, tells the OP the syntax for setting the other tolerances, if that/those were what they really wanted). When OPs do clarify their questions, that's *great*. We're *happy* to reopen such questions. After all, the goal is good, on-topic questions that are useful to future visitors.

Comment: OTOH, I do disagree with the question being deleted at this time. IMO, the full 9 days (or so) of "on hold"/"closed" should have been permitted to pass prior to deletion (either automatic deletion, or by vote), in order to permit the OP additional time to clarify their question.

Comment: Ok. I understand. I am not here to defend the asker, It's just scary to see that I can get one of my question closed for the same reasons, without explaining. I also think that close reasons are sometimes not enough, particularly in this case when the asker visibly had no way of knowing how his question could be interpreted in so many ways. I would have been happy to edit my own question knowing what to clarify, and this could have help other users to provide edit for the asker. I mean, the answer was still good and it got deleted.

Comment: Sad to see that you had experience with users not willing to edit their questions to provide clarifications.

Comment: @V.Brunelle Unfortunately, but understandably, the *vast* majority of users care only about their question being answered sufficiently to solve their problem, and give little, or no, thought to the question and answers being helpful to future visitors. Thus, once they have sufficient information from an answer, they rarely put effort into improving their question. Some, very few, do. Those that do should be strongly encouraged. The portion of OPs that are willing to edit in that situation is also much, much lower for those users with only 1 reputation point (e.g. it's their first question).

Comment: The entire reason that the change of verbiage from [<Closed> to <On Hold>](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173497/380722) in questions was to _encourage_ OP to edit their question. [<On Hold>](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10582/380722) implies that **there's still time** to make constructive changes & make it clear and answerable to allow us to provide a genuine answer. Closing a question was never intended to be an end-all, it was intended to 1.) Notify OP of issues and 2.) Disallow 'guess' answers until clarification is made. IOW - don't take a closed question personally, just fix it.