# Doesn't "Ask questions, get answers, no distractions" undermine the "Search, and research" advice for new users?

Tags: feature-request, help-center, tour-page

**Can we change the large-font motto on the Tour to something less obviously chaotic and destructive than "Ask questions,...?**

Some incredibly high percentage of first questions show little or no effort on the part of the questioner. I don't mean on difficult issues, either. I mean Python programmers who haven't used `type`, `dir`, or `help` to examine the variables and methods that they're asking about, or haven't even tried bits of code inside their loops in isolation, in an interpreter. (One user asked for information about what `pop()` does, and the question was 50x longer than just typing `my_array.pop()` into an interpreter. Madness!)

As daffy and unwelcome as those questions are, SO seems designed to generate and welcome them in their droves with the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) motto: *Ask questions, get answers, no distractions*. Every new user that takes the time to take the tour--And kudos to them for respecting SO enough to do so!--gets immediately led astray in a way that makes SO worse, and contradicts one of the first links that the dutiful post to them, [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We tell them to ask, and then punish them for asking! We shove them into the grinder and blame them for being hamburger.

I realize that, if successful, the total number of, let's be honest, total shit questions would go down, and that that traffic drives a lot of reputation gain. (I shudder to think how much of my own reputation came from answering inane questions because it's quicker and safer than searching and flagging a dupe.) I don't know how badly that decrease in activity would harm SO as an organization. But, right now, the endless flux of syntax, debug-my-typo, and I'd-like-to-use-AI-to-solve-X questions is turning the job of trying to contribute into the [Nothing Grinder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Fn-26Jmi5E&vl=en-US) of Despair.

Comment: I am at risk of stating the obvious, but the intention of the tour motto is to emphasize the debate-less nature of the site, rather than suggest to blatantly ask questions without a care. Can we actually find evidence of people assuming the latter?

Comment: @SirE_net4theDownvoter, how much evidence do we need that people who are told to "Ask questions,..." think that the point of SO is to ask questions? What if the order of the motto were changed? "Find answers, ask questions, no distractions?" And, the "intention" of the motto is less significant than what the motto actually says and how it will be interpreted.

Comment: Questions aren't required to show problem solving effort. Research effort is evaluated based on the existence of duplicate questions. The only effort that a question can lack that really makes it a poor questions is question definition effort.

Comment: @TinyGiant, I hope that you are very, very wrong on all counts. "Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague...," while it continues on to talk about economy of speech, I think mitigates at least a little bit against every of your three points.

Comment: Please see: [You're conflating three different forms of "effort"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260909/4639281). I don't just make this stuff up.

Comment: @TinyGiant: I had no idea how misguided this whole venture is. I stand corrected.

Comment: You may also want to read [What's better: a question with no attempt or with an unfixable/irrelevant attempt?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338755/4639281)

Comment: Almost nobody takes the tour and the few who do are usually the ones we need to worry least about.

Comment: It's in general too easy to ask questions here. IMHO you should need to wait three days from registering your account before you can post a question.

Comment: Maybe you could also add something like that when you start asking a new question, you cannot post it until one hour has passed.

Comment: One answers question detailed on SO, and then billions of others come here and see answer via search-engines. Maybe focus shifts from stacks for expirienced programmers, to stacks for anyones, as users amount increases